# libgdx: mesh color not making it to vertex shader

Tags: opengl, libgdx, glsl, shader

I've implemented my own shader (see below), which I use to render meshes in a ModelBatch.  The shader program seems to be bound correctly as I can see geometry on the screen in the correct locations so the camera transform is also setup correctly.

```
public class ModelShader implements Shader {

    ShaderProgram program;
    Camera camera;
    RenderContext context;
    int u_projTrans;
    int u_worldTrans;

    public void init() {
        String vert = Gdx.files.internal("first_vertex.glsl").readString();
        String frag = Gdx.files.internal("first_fragment.glsl").readString();
        program = new ShaderProgram(vert, frag);
        if (!program.isCompiled()) {
            throw new GdxRuntimeException(program.getLog());
        }
        u_projTrans = program.getUniformLocation("u_projTrans");
        u_worldTrans = program.getUniformLocation("u_worldTrans");
    }

    public void dispose() { ... }

    public void begin(Camera camera, RenderContext context) {
        this.camera = camera;
        this.context = context;
        program.begin();
        program.setUniformMatrix(u_projTrans, camera.combined);
        context.setDepthTest(GL20.GL_LEQUAL);
        context.setCullFace(GL20.GL_BACK);
    }

    public void render(Renderable renderable) {
        program.setUniformMatrix(u_worldTrans, renderable.worldTransform);
        renderable.meshPart.render(program);
    }

    public void end() {
        program.end();
    }

    public int compareTo(Shader other) { ... }

    public boolean canRender(Renderable instance) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The only problem I'm having now is the color isn't coming down.  I have some meshes I setup as below with a diffuse color.

```
model = modelBuilder.createBox(1f, SIZE, SIZE, new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.MAGENTA)), Usage.Position | Usage.Normal);
box = new ModelInstance(model);
```

I've verified the color from the vertex shader is making it to the fragment shader, but when I set the vertex shader varying property to the *a_color*, the scene is all red making me think the color isn't coming down at all.  I had valid colors with these meshes when I was using the builtin shader so I'm doing something wrong.

```
attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec4 a_color;
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;
uniform mat4 u_worldTrans;

varying vec4 vColor;

void main() {
    vColor = a_color; // hard-coding a color will show up on screen
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * u_worldTrans * vec4(a_position, 1.0);
}
```

Is the *a_color* the wrong attribute to use here?  Am I supposed to bind something manually or is that all done by the *meshPart.render()* call?

Comment: Use `diffuseColor` instead of `a_color`.

Comment: That didn't do anything different.  Where is that attribute set?